# Optimization question calculus

Tags: calculus, optimization

In the wake of a natural disaster, a civil engineer is tasked with building a one
room structure, in the form of a rectangular prism. The structure must have a
height of 10ft in order to fit the required equipment to be used in the room. Of
course, there is limited resources. In particular, the civil engineer has only enough
drywall to cover walls with a total surface area of 2000 square feet. Determine the dimensions of the room that give a maximum volume.

Comment: Hello! Have you thought about drawing a room, setting some parameters and translating the problem into equations?

Answer (score 1):

Different ways how this can be done, but assume this rectangular prism to have a front face dimension $x$ by $10$, and the width is $y$.
The surface area would then be $20x$ (front and back) $+40y$ (lateral sides), so $20x+40y=2000$ or simplified $x+2y=100$. I advice you to make a drawing to confirm. Now the volume is $V=LWH=10xy$. Eliminating $y$ in the volume equation using the first equation, gives $V=5x(100-x)=-5x^2+500x$. This is a parabola with a maximum. Can you calculate this maximum and finish the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by calculate the maximum i dont get it so thats why im asking thank you for the help anyways

Comment: When you graph $y=-5x^2+500x$ using a graphing tool, you see that this is a parabola that opens down. This parabola has a vertex that is a maximum. The $x$ value of this vertex gives you the dimensions you need to maximize your volume and once you calculate this $x$, you have access to the maximum volume. My question to you: How do you calculate the coordinates of a parabola's vertex?

Answer (score 0):

We need to solve the following problem.

Find a maximal value of $10ab$ if known that $20(a+b)=2000$, where $a$ and $b$ are positives.

Now, by AM-GM
$$10ab\leq10\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2=10\left(\frac{100}{2}\right)^2=25000.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=50$, which says that $25000$ is a maximal value.

Done!